# how to visualize a map from a binary file in the best way?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

this code given bellow will read a binary file and simply visualize the map as shown bellow
Here is a link to the file

```
firsrow <- file("C:\\LaiAverage_2011_WGS84_50km.img", "rb")
row1 = readBin(firsrow, integer(), size = 2, n = 720*360, signed = F)
y <- matrix(data = row1, ncol = 360, nrow = 720)
image(t(t(y)), ylim=c(1,0)).
```

can anyone help me to visualize it like this instead:

Comment: What kind of binary file? What format?

Comment: Please show us a _reproducible_ example of what you already did, with specific questions like "how can I change the color scale". Right now the question is quite vague, and you are asking us to do a lot of guessing and work.

Comment: why use `t(t(y))` as `y == t(t(y))`, and have you looked at the stuff I suggested in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite broad and vague, therefore my answer will share those qualities. In addition, I will focus on a ggplot2 based solution.

- To change the fill color, look at `scale_fill_*`, where * is e.g. `continuous` or `gradient`.
- to change the layout of the x and y axis, look at `scale_{x,y}_*`, e.g. the `labels` and `breaks` arguments.
- To get high-res output, either save as pdf or high res png. I greatly prefer using `ggsave` for this.