# How to display longitude and latitude lines on a map using R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to view this binary file(unsigned character, pixel =720 and lines=360) as a map   ,I tried the piece of code given bellow. First, I downloaded and saved it as `landcover.bin`.

```
conne <- file("C:\\landcover.bin", "rb")
sd<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=1,  n=360*720, signed=F)
y<-matrix((data=sd), ncol=360, nrow=720)
image(y)
```

I got a map that looks weird, and then I swap ncol and nrow as

```
y<-matrix((data=sd), ncol=720, nrow=360)
image(y)
```

I got a reasonable map but upside down

My question can anyone tell me how can I display my file as (which is not supposed to be the same)and how to display the longitudes and latitudes as are shown on this map:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `raster` package for geographically based gridded data.

You can probably make it read directly from a binary file with some rgdal trickery, but lets do it via a matrix.

```
> require(raster)
> conne <- file("landcover.bin","rb")
> sd<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=1,  n=360*720, signed=F)
> y<-t(matrix((data=sd), ncol=360, nrow=720))
> r = raster(y)
```

Now you have a raster object. But if you plot it you will notice three things - lots of green, the scale going up to 250, and the axes being from 0 to 1.

The map seems to use 255 for the sea. If we recode that as NA we'll get a better map:

```
> r[r==255]=NA
> plot(r)
```

Looks a lot better. Now let's fix the range:

```
> extent(r) = extent(c(xmn=-180,xmx=180,ymn=-90,ymx=90))
> plot(r)
```

Finally we should tell R that this is in the lat-long coordinate system - most likely epsg:4326:

```
> projection(r)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
> plot(r)
```

[image: classified world map]

Note this is still using a continuous colour scheme, even though you have discrete data (which I guess is a classification scheme). You can map numbers to colours with raster, but that's a whole other problem...

Answer (score 4):

You have to mirror the columns on the matrix to get the right result. Use `abline` to draw your lats and longs.

```
conne <- file("Landcover.bin", "rb")
sd<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=1,  n=360*720, signed=F)
y<-matrix(sd,ncol=360,nrow=720)
image(y[,360:1])

lats=seq(-90,90,by=30)
longs=seq(-180,180,by=30) 

trans.lats=(lats+90) / 180
trans.longs=(longs+180) / 360

abline(h=trans.lats,v=trans.longs)
```

[image]

But, as @January mentioned, there are many packages that handle maps. You should use one of them.

Comment: Thanks but why  the values on the axis are 0.0 0.2 0.3  not 30 0  30 .

Comment: Because that is the default for `image`, because you haven't specified your scale. To change this, suppress the x-axis ticks, and calculate your lats and longs, and then use those for the labels. But, again, you should really use an appropriate package for this. This is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Actually, it is the common way to do things in R. Google suppress x-axis in R.

Comment: I managed to  suppress x-axis and y.but didn't understand what you meant by calculate your lats and longs, and then use those for the labels.Could you please show me how I do it?

Comment: After you suppress the axis, use the `axis` command to put it back in. Look up `?axis` and you can see how to modify the labels of the points.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18063/discussion-between-wafa-alyaari-and-nograpes)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 3):

To get a `ggplot2` based solution, you can use `geom_raster`. See my answer to this [earlier question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285120/how-to-visualize-a-map-from-a-netcdf-file) for an example. `ggplot2` displays lat lon lines, to tweak this see my answer to [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439613/how-to-visualize-a-map-from-a-binary-file-in-the-best-way), specifically the `breaks` argument for `scale_{x,y}_*`.

`ggplot2` requires a data.frame, not a `matrix` or `array`, use `melt` to do this transformation (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285120/how-to-visualize-a-map-from-a-netcdf-file)).  To get the correct lat lon values, please take care that the `array` has the correct `dimnames`, please see `?dimnames` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the maps in the R map package would suit you better?

```
library( maps )
map( "world" )
points(  -0.11832, 51.50939, pch= 19, col= "red" )
text(  -0.11832, 51.50939, "London", pos=3, col= "red" )
abline( h= 0 )
text( -150, 0, "Equator", pos= 3 )
abline( v= 0 )
```

Result:

[image]