# How to write multiple bands from netcdf to a binary file?

Tags: r, binary, netcdf

I have netcdf file
I opened it and read one variable:

```
 K=open.ncdf("C:\\hiba_history.nc")
Smonthly= get.var.ncdf(nc=K,varid="evap",verbose=TRUE)

[1] "vobjtodimname: is a character type varid.  This file has 9 dims"
[1] "vobjtodimname: no cases found, returning FALSE"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: isdimvar: FALSE"
[1] "vobjtovarid: entering with varid=evap"
[1] "Variable named evap found in file with varid= 10"
[1] "vobjtovarid: returning with varid deduced from name; varid= 10"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: ending up using varid= 10"
[1] "ndims: 3"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: varsize:"
[1] 34 30 12
[1] "get.var.ncdf: start:"
[1] 1 1 1
[1] "get.var.ncdf: count:"
[1] 34 30 12
[1] "get.var.ncdf: totvarsize: 12240"
[1] "Getting var of type 3  (1=short, 2=int, 3=float, 4=double, 5=char, 6=byte)"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: C call returned 0"
[1] "count.nodegen: 34    Length of data: 12240" "count.nodegen: 30    Length of data: 12240"
[3] "count.nodegen: 12    Length of data: 12240"
[1] "get.var.ncdf: final dims of returned array:"
[1] 34 30 12
[1] "varid: 10"
```

As you can see, this variable has 30 pixel and 34 lines and 12 band(months)
I would like to just write the sum of the 12 so I finally got one file which calculate the sum of all the 12 months(to be annual)

```
      apply(Smonthly, c(1,2), sum) -> Sannual 
  to.write = file(paste("C:\\annual.bin",sep=""),"wb")

   writeBin(as.double(Sannual),to.write,size=4)
```

When I opend the file thru another program,I found that the map(file)was upside-down

Comment: Please specify what did not work, where you unable to calculate the sum, or unable to dump the file? Please make your problem reproducible...

Comment: FYI `paste("C:\\annual.bin",sep="")` is unnecessary, just write `"C:\\annual.bin"`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as summing the 12 months together, here is the way to do it:

```
library(ncdf)
K <- open.ncdf("math.nc")
Smonthly <- get.var.ncdf(nc=K,varid="evap")
apply(Smonthly, c(1,2), sum) -> Sannual 
# Since the months are represented by dimension 3, you apply sum on dimensions 1 and 2
```

As per request here is an attempt to do the same using `raster`:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf)
Smonthly <- raster("math.nc", varname="evap", band=12)
Sannual <- calc(Smonthly, sum)
```

Comment: Just curious, would this be doable with `raster`?

Comment: I'm honestly not very familiar with the `writeBin`/`readBin` routine so I can't really help on that aspect of your question unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

...and once you have the monthly sums, you can just call `writeBin` to save them to file:

```
a = array(runif(10*10*10), dim = c(10,10,10))
a_sum = apply(a, c(1,2), sum)
# Write stuff
writeBin(as.numeric(a_sum), "/tmp/test.bin", size = 4)
# read stuff back in
test = readBin("/tmp/test.bin", numeric(), 10*10, size = 4)
# ...succes???
> head(data.frame(test, as.numeric(a_sum)))
      test as.numeric.a_sum.
1 5.581374          5.581374
2 5.974429          5.974429
3 4.854637          4.854637
4 5.040194          5.040193
5 3.709209          3.709210
6 6.119048          6.119048
>     all.equal(test, as.numeric(a_sum))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 2.313248e-08"
>     all.equal(test, as.numeric(a_sum), tolerance = 1e-7)
[1] TRUE
```

note: why you need to set `tolerance` to get `all.equal` to return `TRUE` I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Then swap the axis, or write you data to the file in reverse order, see e.g. @Spacedman's answer to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897176/how-to-display-longitude-and-latitude-lines-on-a-map-using-r